# How to access fields of documents in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

Currently, I am writing a cloud function, i need a way to get the device id tokens of some devices, which i have stored in a field of a collection in a document.

How can I access it?

Please help, i'm stuck at this.

Comment: Please **share the entire code of your Cloud Function** and indicate the document from which you want to get the fields Is it the doc that triggered the Cloud Function? Another one?

Answer (score 2):

You can try code:

```
firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
            Firestore.instance.collection('collectionName').document(currentUserId).updateData({'pushToken': token});
        })
```